# How to await the result of setting an interface up (ip link set up)?

Tags: kernel, network-interface

`ip link set up eth0` is not blocking. After returning, its result is only visible in the system a few μ/msecs later, mostly accompanied by a kernel message of the device driver, like `r8169 0000:25:00.0 eth0: link up`.

At this point, e.g. `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` is initialized and stores the values `up` or `down`, depending on whether a cable is connected in case of an ethernet device. Before bringing the link up, `operstate` is always `down`.

How can I wait for the result of `ip link set up`, i.e. the moment where `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` and other `eth0/*` files hold their updated values?

Answer (score 1):

```
until [ "$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate)" = "up" ]; do sleep 1;done
```

Comment: This never halts in case of an ethernet iface with no cable attached.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's only waiting for `up` state of `eth0` as you asked for.

Comment: No, I want to wait for the resulting state after `ip link set up`, which is not necessarily `up`.

Comment: @ens So you just want anything other than "down"? That should be easy to do, does something like `until [ "state" != "down" ]` work?

Comment: @Xen2050, no I want to wait until the result of `ip set up` is visible in the system,  i.e. the moment when, for example, the value of `operstate` truly indicates whether a cable is attached or not.

Comment: Didn't know operstate would "flicker" between values for a few seconds - how do you know when it's finally done? Just wait a fixed few seconds, regardless of the value in operstate? Or monitor syslog for a specific message?

Comment: `operstate` doesn't flicker. As stated above, it's `down` initially and then goes `up`or stays `down`.